# Java actionPerformed not applying to other methods

Tags: java, swing, applet

Here's the initialization of the controls.

```
public void init(){
    ...
    c = new JComboBox();
    ....
    c.addActionListener(this);

    p2 = new JPanel();
    vt = new Vector();
    ChannelList cl = new ChannelList();

    lchannels = new JList(vt);   
    lchannels.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    jp = new JScrollPane(lchannels);
    cl.createList();

    p2.add(jp);
    p2.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Channel Titles Available"));  
    p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1,10,10));
}
```

The part of actionPerformed() method is supposed to determine the selection from JCombobox, and put the correct objects to JList.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JComboBox c = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
    String genre = (String)c.getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println(genre);

    vt = new Vector();
    ChannelList cl = new ChannelList();

    lchannels = new JList(vt);   
    lchannels.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    jp = new JScrollPane(lchannels);
    cl.createList();

    for(int i =0; i < cl.chList.length; i++){
        char chGenre = cl.chList[i].getChGenre();
        switch(genre){
        case "All Genres":
            vt.add(cl.chList[i].getChTitle());
            break;
        case "Entertainment":
            if(chGenre == 'e')
                vt.add(cl.chList[i].getChTitle());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a part of ChannelList:

```
public void createList()
{

    chList = new ChannelInfo[19];

    chList[0] = new ChannelInfo("BBC Canada",3.99, 5.99,'e',"bbccan.jpg");
    chList[1] = new ChannelInfo("Bloomberg TV",3.99, 5.99,'n',"bloom.jpg");
    ...
}
```

There is no error message while running the program. The first part of actionPerformed which prints the String is working properly (which is useless).
However, there's no result showing in JList.

In order to make it more clear, here's the whole file:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.util.*; 

public class AS4Temp extends JApplet implements ItemListener, ActionListener{
JPanel p,p1,p2;

JComboBox c;
JList lchannels;
JScrollPane jp;
Vector vt;
Container con;

public void init(){
    p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3,10,10));

    //Genre
    p1 = new JPanel();
    c = new JComboBox();
    c.addItem("Please Select Genre of Channel");
    c.addItem("All Genres");
    c.addItem("Entertainment");
    c.addItem("Movie");
    c.addItem("News/Business");
    c.addItem("Sci-Fi");
    c.addItem("Sports");

    c.addActionListener(this);

    p1.add(c);

    p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    p1.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Channel Genre"));

    //Channels

    p2 = new JPanel();
    vt = new Vector();
    ChannelList cl = new ChannelList();

    lchannels = new JList(vt);   
    lchannels.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    jp = new JScrollPane(lchannels);
    cl.createList();
    /*
    for(int i =0; i < cl.chList.length; i++){
        char chGenre = cl.chList[i].getChGenre();
        if(chGenre == 'e')
        vt.add(cl.chList[i].getChTitle());
    }*/
    p2.add(jp);
    p2.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Channel Titles Available"));  
    p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1,10,10));

    //all panels
    p.add(p1);
    p.add(p2);

    con = getContentPane();
    con.add(p);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JComboBox c = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
    String genre = (String)c.getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println(genre);

    ChannelList cl = new ChannelList();
    cl.createList();

    switch(genre){
    case "All Genres":
        for(int i =0; i < cl.chList.length; i++){
            char chGenre = cl.chList[i].getChGenre();
            vt.add(cl.chList[i].getChTitle());
        }
        break;
    case "Entertainment":
        for(int i =0; i < cl.chList.length; i++){
            char chGenre = cl.chList[i].getChGenre();
            if(chGenre == 'e')
                vt.add(cl.chList[i].getChTitle());
        }
        break;
    }

    /*
    for(int i =0; i < cl.chList.length; i++){
        char chGenre = cl.chList[i].getChGenre();
        switch(genre){
        case "All Genres":
            vt.add(cl.chList[i].getChTitle());
            break;
        case "Entertainment":
            if(chGenre == 'e')
                vt.add(cl.chList[i].getChTitle());
            break;
            }
        }*/
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that your posted code and text is adequate to allow us to be able to understand your problem enough to answer it. If you don't get a decent answer soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Don't create a new JList, just create a new ListModel and apply it to the existing JList

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing here based on partial information, but I see you creating new components including a new JList and a new JScrollPane:

```
lchannels = new JList(vt);   
lchannels.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
jp = new JScrollPane(lchannels);
```

But I don't see that JScrollPane being added to anything, and so it would make sense that none of that would display.

It seems that you may want to go about this very differently, that rather than creating a `new JList()` and `new JScrollPane(...)` you probably want to create a new JList model and set the **existing** JList with this new model, either that or simply change the data held by the existing JList model.

Consider creating a DefaultListModelField object inside of your actionPerformed method, say called `listModel, calling`addElement(...)` on it to fill it with data, and then call

```
myList.setModel(listModel);
```

on your existing and **displayed** JList.

---

For example, here is my [minimal example program, or MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Mcve extends JPanel {
   private static final String[] DATA = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};

   private DefaultComboBoxModel<String> comboModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
   private JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(comboModel);

   private DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
   private JList<String> list = new JList<>(listModel);

   public Mcve() {
      list.setPrototypeCellValue(String.format("%30s", " "));
      list.setVisibleRowCount(10);;

      // fill combo box's model with a bunch of junk
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < DATA.length; j++) {
            String text = DATA[j] + " " + i;
            comboModel.addElement(text);
         }
      }

      Action buttonAction = new ButtonAction("Transfer Data");
      comboBox.addActionListener(buttonAction);

      add(comboBox);
      add(new JScrollPane(list, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED));
      add(new JButton(buttonAction));
   }

   private class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
      public ButtonAction(String name) {
         super(name);
         int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         Object selection = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
         if (selection != null) {
            listModel.addElement(selection.toString());
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Mcve mainPanel = new Mcve();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mcve");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

---

You're using a Vector in place of list model, and you seem to be assuming that changing the Vector later on in your program will change the JList -- but it won't. Instead get rid of that Vector, `vt`, and again please do what I recommend -- use a `DefaultListModel` in its place. For example, please see changes to code below. Changes are marked with `// !!` comments:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class AS4Temp extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
   JPanel p, p1, p2;

   JComboBox c;
   JList lchannels;
   JScrollPane jp;
   // !! Vector vt;
   private DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>(); // !!
   Container con;

   public void init() {
      p = new JPanel();
      p.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 10, 10));

      // Genre
      p1 = new JPanel();
      c = new JComboBox();
      c.addItem("Please Select Genre of Channel");
      c.addItem("All Genres");
      c.addItem("Entertainment");
      c.addItem("Movie");
      c.addItem("News/Business");
      c.addItem("Sci-Fi");
      c.addItem("Sports");

      c.addActionListener(this);

      p1.add(c);

      p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      p1.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Channel Genre"));

      // Channels

      p2 = new JPanel();
      // !! vt = new Vector();
      ChannelList cl = new ChannelList();

      // !! lchannels = new JList(vt);
      lchannels = new JList<>(listModel); // !!

      lchannels.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
      jp = new JScrollPane(lchannels);
      cl.createList();
      /*
       * for(int i =0; i < cl.chList.length; i++){ char chGenre =
       * cl.chList[i].getChGenre(); if(chGenre == 'e')
       * vt.add(cl.chList[i].getChTitle()); }
       */
      p2.add(jp);
      p2.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Channel Titles Available"));
      p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 10, 10));
      // price

      // all panels
      p.add(p1);
      p.add(p2);

      con = getContentPane();
      con.add(p);
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      JComboBox c = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
      String genre = (String) c.getSelectedItem();
      System.out.println(genre);

      ChannelList cl = new ChannelList();
      cl.createList();

      switch (genre) {
      case "All Genres":
         for (int i = 0; i < cl.chList.length; i++) {
            char chGenre = cl.chList[i].getChGenre();
            // !! vt.add(cl.chList[i].getChTitle());
            listModel.addElement(cl.chList[i].getChTitle()); // !!
         }
         break;
      case "Entertainment":
         for (int i = 0; i < cl.chList.length; i++) {
            char chGenre = cl.chList[i].getChGenre();
            if (chGenre == 'e')
               // !! vt.add(cl.chList[i].getChTitle());
               listModel.addElement(cl.chList[i].getChTitle()); // !!
         }
         break;
      }

   }
}

// !! added to make your code compilable
// !! in the future, please don't force us to do this kludge
class ChannelList {

   public Channel[] chList;

   public ChannelList() {
      createList();
   }

   public void createList() {
      chList = new Channel[5];
      chList[0] = new Channel("Foobar1", 'e');
      chList[1] = new Channel("Foobar2", 'e');
      chList[2] = new Channel("Foobar3", 'e');
      chList[3] = new Channel("Foobar4", 'e');
      chList[4] = new Channel("Foobar5", 'e');
   }

}

// !! added to make your code compilable
// !! in the future, please don't force us to do this kludge
class Channel {
   private String title;
   private char genre;

   public Channel(String title, char genre) {
      this.title = title;
      this.genre = genre;
   }

   public char getChGenre() {
      return genre;
   }

   public String getChTitle() {
      return title;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return "Channel [title=" + title + ", genre=" + genre + "]";
   }

}
```

Comment: Actually, what I really need in `actionPerforment()` method is just to `getSelectedItem` from the `JCombobox`, and the `for()` loop to add the list. Those controls and variables are declared again in order to fix the errors in the loop.

Comment: @hanab: so you've fixed your problem?

Comment: I deleted the unnecessary part between `System.out.println()` and `for()` loop, but still don't know how to display the JList. I'm learning how to use DefaultListModelField object.

Comment: @hanabinoir: if you're still stuck, then create and post into your original program your [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), similar to the code that I've created and posted above.

Comment: Do you also want to see my `ArrayList` file?

Comment: @hanabinoir: I honestly want to see your [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please read the link), no more and no less. You can start with mine and modify it so that it reproduces your problem for us. You've posted your whole file, and most of that code is completely unrelated to your problem, forcing us to wade through tons of nonrelevant code -- not a nice thing to ask of volunteers. Please pare your code down so that it still compiles, still runs, but has just enough to show us your problem without all the other unrelated crap.

Comment: @hanabinoir: not only that, your mountain of code won't compile and run for us since it's missing other dependent classes. But don't post those, instead isolate your error with an MCVE.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. What parts do you mean by "original program",? e.g. `import`,`class`,etc...

Comment: @hanabinoir: oops that was a typo and should read "into your original *question*".

Comment: @hanabinoir: you're using a Vector in place of list model, and you seem to be assuming that changing the Vector later on in your program will change the JList -- but it won't. Instead get rid of that Vector, `vt`, and again please do what I recommend -- use a DefaultListModel in its place. You won't regret doing this.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I copied the code from my lab exercise, but I got frustrated by the Vector. Our instructor ask us to use JList (with Vector in his examples), but if it doesn't work, I'll learn to use DefaultListModel.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is you are adding a new `JList` on `actionPerformed()` and you have not added the list to the container.

```
lchannels = new JList(vt);
```

Well you don't need to add a new list on selection, all you need is to update the list model itself on selection.